Unusual folder access on Ubuntu (does this happen to other people or is a malware casually skimming all of my data)
I don't know what it is or if it's normal. All I know is that I have not accessed these folders any time recently. The event appears to have happened many times before.
I am scared of the prospective of getting malware.
I'm on Ubuntu. I was normally coding and opened up VSCode and I saw that lots of folders that I usually don't access were accessed at the same time all of them together.
i was wondering if this may be a software bug or a malware that is casually skimming all of my information and sending it somewhere.
The time is 11:44.

